# Using do.call to create ui in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I was seeing if it was possible to use do.call to create an R Shiny ui function and am at a loss to understand the issue below. Firstly if I do a basic example without do.call...

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("A title"),
  fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content",))
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

...then this renders as expected with a page that shows "A title" and "some content" under.

Then if I try to do what I think is exactly the same using do.call as below...

```
library(shiny)

page_data <- c(
  titlePanel("A title"),
  fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content",))
)
ui <- do.call(fluidPage, as.list(page_data))

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

... then this does not render the same page. Interestingly it does run without error and shows "A title" but not "some content". Any ideas to explain why it would render differently? And also is it possible to implement using a do.call type interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a list instead of a vector at the beginning, and therefore not use `as.list()` later. However, I don't know why using `list()` is different than `as.list(c())`:

```
library(shiny)

page_data <- list(
  titlePanel("A title"),
  fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content",))
)
ui <- do.call(fluidPage, page_data)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit:** actually, we can see some differences between the two expressions:

```
list(
  titlePanel("A title"),
  fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content",))
)

[[1]]
<h2>A title</h2>

[[2]]
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">some content</div>
</div>
```

```
as.list(c(
  titlePanel("A title"),
  fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content",))
))

[[1]]


[[2]]
<h2>A title</h2>

$name
[1] "div"

$attribs
$attribs$class
[1] "row"


$children
$children[[1]]
<div class="col-sm-12">some content</div>
```

Comment: That's so interesting, I would have assumed that calling as.list of a vector would result in the same as creating the list itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is actually not `as.list` but `c`.
Shiny UI functions do not return plain HTML as one could think, but a `shiny.tag` object (or `shiny.tag.list` list if several `shiny.tag` objects are grouped together).
A `shiny.tag` object is a list that contains information about the name of the HTML tag used and its children (e.g. other tags and its contents, for more information have a look [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/advanced-ui.html#introduction-to-html)).
The reason we see the HTML code when a `shiny.tag` object is printed is because there are special `print` and `as.character` methods for `shiny.tag` and `shiny.tag.list` objects.

Have a look at the output of `fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content"))`:

```
str(fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content")))
List of 3
 $ name    : chr "div"
 $ attribs :List of 1
  ..$ class: chr "row"
 $ children:List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ name    : chr "div"
  .. ..$ attribs :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ class: chr "col-sm-12"
  .. ..$ children:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr "some content"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
```

Internally it's a list! However, if printed it outputs:

```
print(fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content")))
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">some content</div>
</div>
```

The same is true for `titlePanel("A title")`, it actually generates 2 `shiny.tag` objects in a `shiny.tag.list`:

```
str(titlePanel("A title"))
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ name    : chr "head"
  ..$ attribs : Named list()
  ..$ children:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr "title"
  .. .. ..$ attribs : Named list()
  .. .. ..$ children:List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "A title"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ name    : chr "h2"
  ..$ attribs : Named list()
  ..$ children:List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr "A title"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "shiny.tag.list" "list"
```

If you combine this as a list, the single `shiny.tag` objects still retain their list structure, so it's no problem for `do.call(fluidPage, page_data_list)` to generate the UI.
You basically create a list of lists:

```
page_data_list <- list(
  titlePanel("A title"),
  fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content"))
)

str(page_data_list, max.level = 1)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "shiny.tag.list" "list"
 $ :List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
```

However, `c` tries to combine lists. The existing list objects don't get their own list in the newly created list, but the highest list levels get combined (`c` basically appends the lists):

```
page_data <- c(
  titlePanel("A title"),
  fluidRow(column(width = 12,"some content"))
)

str(page_data, max.level = 1)
List of 5
 $         :List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 $         :List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 $ name    : chr "div"
 $ attribs :List of 1
 $ children:List of 1
```

`as.list(page_data)` doesn't change anything because `page_data` is already a list.

Now the `shiny.tag` objects don't have the correct structure anymore and `do.call(fluidPage, page_data)` doesn't work.